# Creating a login page using shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating a login page . I am using SharedPreferences here . The problem is i am getting wrong password always when the checkbox "remember me" is checked . Without using sharedpreferences the code works fine . Can anybody give me a solution ? Thanks in advance .

```
public class UserLoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);

preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogIn);
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginEmail);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
remember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRemember);
uID = preference.getString("userid", " ");
uPass = preference.getString("pass_word", " ");

username.setText(uID);
password.setText(uPass);
login.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v){
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bLogIn:
        if(remember.isChecked()){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
            editor.putString("userid", username.getText().toString().trim());
            editor.putString("pass_word", password.getText().toString().trim());                            
            editor.commit();

            login();
            }else {
                login();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uID = preference.getString("userid", " ");
uPass = preference.getString("pass_word", " ");
```

You return space by default, so your login and password always have spaces. When you store the credentials, you trim them, thus deleting the space. So you create account like `'username '` and store it as `'username'`. Same with password. Thit may be the reason your code doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah ! You are right . I solved the proble just after posting the question here . Thanks for replying .